# How to run end to end tests with Heroku Ci/pipeline?

Tags: node.js, heroku, continuous-integration, e2e-testing

Hello Guys i have a Question :)

We are using Heroku CI to build our App and we are also using heroku pipelines for the whole process. What would be the best practice here to run end to end tests? I was trying to integrate nightwatch but it seems like this is not the right approche because it needs chrome and java for selenium. It is a Node Application. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the Answer : We had an issue with our nightwatch config in the chromeOptions.args we had something like this : 
`'window-size=1000, 800'`.
But you are not allowed to use whitespaces so just changed it to `'window-size=1000,800'`. Now it works.